# Как найти нечеткие совпадения в двух массивах?

Tags: php, php7

У меня есть два массива, мне нужно найти все пересечения и их индекс(ключ).
Вроде бы все просто но.

```
$array1 = array('мой шумный дом', 'хранитель лев', 'крутые ступени', 'королевство кошек', ' рожденные на воле', ' вспомни, что будет');
$array2 = array('русалочка', 'хранитель лев', 'дитя человеческое', 'королевство кошек', ' кордон следователя савельева', ' вспомни, что будет');

print_r(array_intersect($array1, $array2));
Результат: 
Array ( [1] => хранитель лев [3] => королевство кошек [5] => вспомни, что будет )
```

Но проблема возникает когда необходим нечеткий поиск. К примеру в первом массиве $array1 хранятся точные значения, а в массиве $array2 не точные с лишним мусором.

```
 $array1 = array('мой шумный дом', 'хранитель лев', 'крутые ступени', 'королевство кошек', ' рожденные на воле', ' вспомни, что будет');
 $array2 = array('русалочка', 'хранитель лев (2009)', 'дитя человеческое', 'королевство кошек 2 сезон', 'кордон следователя савельева', 'вспомни, что будет (русская озвучка)');
```

Каким образом можно получить такой результат?:

```
Array ( [1] => хранитель лев (2009) [3] => королевство кошек 2 сезон [5] => вспомни, что будет (русская озвучка) )
```

Comment: если мусор всегда после, можно, казалось бы,  сравнивать начала строк, но это сильно чревато ошибками. Если вы критерий понимаете - https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-uintersect.php

Comment: @splash58 Спасибо, за наводку

Answer (score 0):

Можно собрать динамический шаблон из первого массива, и получить необходимый набор во втором массиве:

```
$array1 = array('мой шумный дом', 'хранитель лев', 'крутые ступени', 'королевство кошек', ' рожденные на воле', ' вспомни, что будет');
$array2 = array('русалочка', 'хранитель лев (2009)', 'дитя человеческое', 'королевство кошек 2 сезон', 'кордон следователя савельева', 'вспомни, что будет (русская озвучка)');

preg_replace_callback(
    array_map(function($i){ return '~' . trim($i) . '.*~'; }, $array1),
    function($m)use(&$arr){ $arr[] = $m[0]; },
    $array2
);

print_r($arr);
```

---

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => хранитель лев (2009)
    [1] => королевство кошек 2 сезон
    [2] => вспомни, что будет (русская озвучка)
)
```

Только в таком случае индексы будут сброшены.

Answer (score 0):

Пока реализовал вот так, костыль, но дает лучшую выборку. но не решает проблемы если мусорный текст присутствует в начале строки.

```
function myfoo($v1,$v2)
{
    $v2 = substr($v2,0,strlen($v1));
    if ($v1===$v2){
        return 0;
    }
    else
    if ($v1 > $v2) return 1;
        return -1;
    }
}

$array1 = array('мой шумный дом', 'хранитель лев', 'крутые ступени', 'королевство кошек', 'рожденные на воле', 'вспомни, что будет');
$array2 = array('русалочка', 'хранитель лев (2009)', 'дитя человеческое', 'королевство кошек 2 сезон', 'кордон следователя савельева', 'вспомни, что будет (русская озвучка)');

print_r(array_uintersect($array1, $array2,'myfoo'));
```