# Какой алгоритм работы у array_uintersect?

Tags: php, php7

В продолжение темы: [Как найти нечеткие совпадения в двух массивах?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1035232/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%85-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%85/1035249#1035249)

Как работает `array_uintersect`?
У меня есть два массива, мне нужно найти все пересечения и их индекс(ключ).
Но проблема возникает когда необходим нечеткий поиск. 
К примеру в первом массиве `$array1` хранятся точные значения, 
а в массиве `$array2` неточные с лишним мусором.
Делаю так

```
function myfoo2($v1,$v2){
    if (preg_match("/".$v1."/", $v2, $matches)){
        if (count($matches)>0) {
            return 0;
        }
        if(count($matches)===0){
            return 1; 
        }
        return -1;
    }
}

$array1 = array('мой шумный дом', 'хранитель лев', 'крутые ступени', 'королевство кошек', ' рожденные на воле', ' вспомни, что будет');
$array2 = array('русалочка', ' мусор хранитель лев (2009)', 'дитя человеческое', 'мусор королевство кошек 2 сезон', 'кордон следователя савельева', 'мусор вспомни, что будет (русская озвучка)');

print_r(array_uintersect($array1, $array2,'myfoo2'));
```

Хочу получить результат

```
Array ( 
    [1] => хранитель лев (2009) 
    [3] => королевство кошек 2 сезон 
    [5] => вспомни, что будет (русская озвучка) 
 )
```

Comment: array_intersect сортирует массивы, а затем идет по ключам. Вы, наверное, можете попробовать возвращать 0, когда preg_match сработал, а иначе strcmp($v1,$v2)

Comment: `preg_grep('/' . implode('|', $array1) . '/', $array2);`

Comment: @u_mulder Спасибо